# If $H$ is a connected subgraph of $G$ show that $T(H)\le T(G)$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-proofs

Defining $T$:
Given a connected graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, let $T(G)$ count the number of sequences $$x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}$$ of the vertices of $G$ such that the induced subgraphs $$G_{i}=G[x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{i}]$$ are connected.

Example:
Take the cyclic graph $C_{4}$. $T(C_{4})=4*2^{4-2}=16$ since we start with 4 vertices to choose from (meaning if removed, the graph is still connected), then 2 (either of the 1-connected vertices), then 2 again (at this point the graph has 2 vertices and 1 edge; we count the graph of a single point).

What is known:
$G$ is a connected graph.
$H$ is a subgraph of $G$, and $H$ is connected.

What to show:
$T(H)\le T(G)$.

Work done:
To be honest, I don't even know where to start. If the subgraph was induced then I could make an argument considering the induced edges, but that is not specified in the problem statement so if I use that, I only considered *half* of the proof, at least I believe. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Basically, any sequence for $H$ can be extended to make a sequence for $G$, so this gives you an injection from sequences for $H$ to sequences for $G$.

Comment: How does that cover the non-induced property of possibly differing edges? Could that not have a significant impact on the combinatorial counting?

Answer (score 1):

Given a subgraph  $H$ of $G$, let $K$ be the induced version of $H$. This means $K$ has the same vertex set as $H$, and all induced edges from $G$. You have proved that $T(K)\le T(G)$.

I claim that $T(H)\le T(K)$. Indeed, since $K$ as all the edges that $H$ has, for any sequence of vertices $x_1,\dots,x_k$ of $K$. we have
$$
\forall i\quad H[x_1,\dots,x_i]\text{ is connected} \quad\implies\quad K[x_1,\dots,x_i]\text{ is connected}
$$
This is true since adding edges to a connected graph preserves connectedness.

It follows that every valid sequence for $T(H)$ is one for $T(K)$, and we conclude $T(H)\le T(K)\le T(G)$.

Comment: You combinatorial mathematicians are a new breed. Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry to comment spam (new to this site; IDK how strict or loose the mods are), but I just had a thought:
Given $H$ is a subgraph of $G$, does your proof imply that any edge present in $H$ must be in $G$?

Comment: Yes, it does. $H$ being a subgraph of $G$ implies every edge in $H$ is also in $G$.